# What would be the potential effects of not having an accumulator in the hydraulic system?

Tags: aircraft-systems, hydraulic-system

In an aircraft, what would be the potential effect of not having an accumulator in the hydraulic system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accumulators act as storage for flow. At times of peak flow demand, the accumulator delivers a large flow supply at nominal pressure until its oil has been used up, after which the maximum flow is the pump flow. The same functionality that a capacitor or a battery has in an electric system.

If there are no accumulators installed:

- Peak hydraulic power is greatly reduced: peak flow supply equals the pump flow, and pressure drops when the pump supplies high flow.
- Pressure surges are high when the pump is running and demand suddenly stops, the accumulator evens out the pressure peak, again like how a capacitor functions. (From @Gerry comment).

Comment: They also absorb pressure spikes when the pumps are running and demand suddenly drops, just as a capacitor will absorb a current surge.

Comment: Thx, have added.

Comment: I think I read about it somewhere that the vibration from the pump that travels in the form of vibrating pressure has caused failures on the pipe on a test aircraft prototype. IIRC that should be XB-70 AV1.